# Add a cylinder on a flat surface

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm trying to make a model of a speaker and I have modeled it until this stage where I need to make a volume knob for it. And I'm not sure how to go about for it.

[image]

[image]
By sheer luck, the knob size is about the circle in picture 2, which is touching two edges.

My idea is to just make loop cuts and then extrude it out but that just turns into a big rectangle block, which is not good.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Create this topology, select this edge loop and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and drag (or tweak the *Operator* box parameters) to make it a circle; or enable the *LoopTools* addon and right click > *LoopTools > Circle*:

[image]

Here is what you get:

[image]

You can continue to model (extrude down, etc):

[image]